# Specify apk for tablets and phones

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

What is the best way to target just phones and tablets for an android application? Meaning, I want to exclude TVs (do not allow users with a googleTV to download the app).

I've seen the following for small and normal size screens, regardless of screen density. It seems like a bit of an overkill, is there a more concise way?

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: `do not allow users with a googleTV to download the app` - why?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski App is better suited for the phone and tablet experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Android applications do **not** appear compatible with Google TV devices - they require the following line added to their `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

So you shouldn't have to do anything to exclude Google TV devices or any other future devices that don't have a touchscreen.